# Node packing data using buffer

Tags: python, node.js, buffer

Any one know how to convert this python snippet in nodejs:

```
return "".join(reversed(struct.pack('I',data)))
```

I tried to make the same in nodejs using Buffer like this:

```
var buff = new Buffer(4).fill(0);
    buff.writeInt16LE(data, 0);
    return new Buffer(buff.reverse().toString('hex'),'hex');
```

But it not work exactly like python snippet, some data make my program stuck and it gave me this error:

```
buffer.js:830
    throw new TypeError('value is out of bounds');
    ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `data` is a valid 16-bit signed integer. That means it must be a valid integer from -32,768 to 32,767.

However, the 'I' in Python's `struct.pack()` is for unsigned 32-bit integers, so what you should instead be using is `buff.writeUInt32LE(data, 0)`.

Comment: My int number must go from 0 to 4294967295 (00000000 - FFFFFFFF) my function must convert int to hex example : 

convert int 1 to \x01 and add padding \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01

Comment: You should be using `writeUInt32LE()` instead of `writeInt16LE()` for `struct.pack('I', ...)`